# Connecting to cassandra cqlsh from remote server with SSL Enabled

Tags: ssl, cassandra, cqlsh

I have a Kubernetes that runs 3 node cassandra cluster. when I try to connect to cqlsh from the local machine it works fine. but after enabling SSL on the cluster, I am seeing the below error. I tried setting up the cqlshrc on my local machine and also kubernetes pods but still the same error. can someone help me?

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty --restart=Never --rm --image cassandra cqlsh -- cqlsh cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local -u cassandra -p password --ssl
Validation is enabled; SSL transport factory requires a valid certfile to be specified. Please provide path to the certfile in [ssl] section as 'certfile' option in /root/.cassandra/cqlshrc (or use [certfiles] section) or set SSL_CERTFILE environment variable.
pod "cqlsh" deleted
pod default/cqlsh terminated (Error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to troublshoot:

1. Check the subject,validity,issuer of remote node certificate (host-remote) from host-local

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host-remote:cassandra -ssl -port 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -subject -dates -issuer
```

2. Check `cqlsh.cer.pem` it may only one entry and has subject with `CN=host-local`, **this can be a possible reason that you are able to connect to local but not a remote host**.

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in path to trustore in cqlhrc file/cqlsh.cer.pem
```

Your truststore shoud have root certificate/CA certificate as well to connect to a remote host by successfully validating the certificate chain, which is coming from remote node.

You may need to embed the root certificate in trutstore.

Refer [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secSslTOC.html) to apply SSL in in cassandra.